# drop multiple tables in proc sql (via teradata)

Tags: sql, sas, teradata

I am trying to drop multiple tables, using the following code, but it raises an error.

**the code:**

```
    PROC SQL ;
        CONNECT TO teradata AS TERADATA (server=dbc  mode=teradata) ;
        EXECUTE (drop table TABLE_NAME1, TABLE_NAME2, TABLE_NAME3  ) BY teradata ;
        DISCONNECT FROM teradata ;
    QUIT ;
```

**the error:** 
syntax error: expecting something between NAME1 and TABLE

Comment: You can only drop one table at a time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you. does that qualify only to sas ? since I have seen it is possible in sql server.

Comment: . . No.  That is how Teradata (and most databases) work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/eWpPpcMoLGQcZEoyt5AjEg/_dStmupz5oB_bFZZ3G89Fw) for `drop` in Teradata, you will see that it operates on only one table:

> Drops the definition for the specified table from the data dictionary and drops the object from its containing database or user, depending on the keyword specified.

This is how most databases work.  You need to do three drops:

```
drop table TABLE_NAME1;
drop table TABLE_NAME2;
drop table TABLE_NAME3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all objects in the database with one command:

```
DELETE DATABASE name_database;
```

but also views, triggers, stored procedures, user-defined functions, and macros will be deleted.